# Left Join when looking for no matches

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have 3 tables and I am pretty sure I need to use a left join when joining the 3rd however the join between the first 2 tables I think just needs to be a regular join and I'm not sure if that requires some kind of nesting or not.

So the first 2 tables (once I set my conditions) should always work out to a 1 to 1 relationship. Then I need to join that to the 3rd table but I need to know if there is no match (which means i need a left join here). Essentially that's all I need to know in this query and actually want to filter table 3 and only show if it is NULL. Furthermore those NULL responses I want to see (or lack thereof) have a date field. I also want to only see that there is NO record for today's date in table 3.

At the end of the day I want to know when there is no record existing in table 3 for todays date for the primary key in table 1/2 (since the way that first join works even though there is a primary/foreign key relation,  the primary key of table 1 is all that matters when matching on table 3.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    subscribers.*, 
    check_times.* 
FROM subscribers, check_times 
LEFT JOIN checks 
    ON checks.subscriber_id = check_times.subscriber_id 
WHERE 
    subscribers.subscriber_id = check_times.subscriber_id 
    AND check_times.dow = 1 
    AND check_times.time <= '19:52' 
    AND checks.date = '2015-02-16' 
    AND checks.status IS NULL
```

Comment: Is there a problem? You could elaborate this by providing sample data and expected results.

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server??

Comment: So exactly what's the problem and your question!!?? show us sample data and structures, also show what you tried before asking

Comment: Sorry guys, MYSQL
SELECT subscribers.*, check_times.* FROM subscribers, check_times LEFT JOIN checks ON checks.subscriber_id = check_times.subscriber_id WHERE subscribers.subscriber_id = check_times.subscriber_id AND check_times.dow = 1 AND check_times.time <= '19:52' AND checks.date = '2015-02-16' AND checks.status IS NULL

Comment: That yields me a completely empty result set. It also doesnt seem to be even trying to do the left join but I get no errors:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're referencing the table in the `LEFT JOIN` on the `WHERE` clause, it became an `INNER JOIN`. What you want is to put them in the `JOIN` condition.

```
SELECT 
    subscribers.*, 
    check_times.* 
FROM subscribers, 
INNER JOIN check_times
    ON subscribers.subscriber_id = check_times.subscriber_id
LEFT JOIN checks 
    ON checks.subscriber_id = check_times.subscriber_id 
    AND checks.date = '2015-02-16'
WHERE    
    check_times.dow = 1 
    AND check_times.time <= '19:52' 
    AND checks.status IS NULL
```

Also, please refrain from using the old-style `JOIN`. Read on this for more info:

- [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: That is not the only problem. Comma has lower precedence then explicit joins.